# Android Emulator: Use Android (soft)keybord

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Hello i only found Questions"how you work with your Pc Keyboard" but however that worked already when I started my emulator. I want to use the Android Keyboard within the emulator itself. As for now the keyboard is not even displaced.

Comment: There should be a setting for that on the emulator itself.  At least Genymotion has it, I assume Google's does too.  I don't suggest it unless you're writing a keyboard though-  it's annoying to click all the keys, and Swype isn't as nice as a real keyboard.  Except for maybe a quick test to make sure the keyboard displays ok, but I'd rather do that on the device.

Comment: I need for a special Test, otherwise i wouldnt need it.

Comment: found it i just needed to uncheck the hardware keybord option in the SVD for my Emulator!